# Did Heisenberg say free will could arise from quantum probabilistic mechanics?

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, philosophy-of-science, quote, heisenberg

I see this view attributed to him a lot during Twitter debates but I never found the source for it

does anyone know if Heisenberg actually held this view/suggested it?

Comment: Is it possible that they are referring to the German neurobiologist [Martin Heisenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Heisenberg), who wrote on the subject of free will, rather than the physicist Werner Heisenberg, who saw the problem of free will as one for philosophers.

Comment: Owen Gingerich, "More than Machines." In Kelly K. Monroe (ed.), *Finding God at Harvard*, Grand Rapids, MI: Zondervan 1996, p. 267-274: " *Nearly twenty years ago Heisenberg gave a public lecture at Harvard, and in the discussion period one of my graduate students asked if he had ever thought about the relation of his uncertainty principle to free will. At this, the other physics students ... hissed so loudly that Heisenberg did not bother to answer.* " Same source goes on to speculate what Heisenberg may have thought about the issue. So far I can't find evidence that he made a statement on it